# Pushing to a friends repo

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a friends git repo using the url by

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo_name.git
```

I then created my branch, committed and attempted to push my code to a new branch, by

```
git push --set-upstream origin my_branch_name
```

However, I get the following message after entering my username and password correctly (I checked)

```
remote: Permission to user/reo_name.git denied to my_git.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I'm new to git so I have no clue what I've done wrong/need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're listed as one of the repository's contributor, you can't push changes directly to it.

You should fork the repository in order to create a personal copy of the original repository.

After you have it under your username, you should create a branch, propose changes, and create a pull-request to the original repository.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to git, can you explain a bit more what you mean by "fork the repository" and "create a pull request"?

Comment: @dilan_s https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo